# Slang or idioms for someone in a doomed situation

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, slang

Are there any idioms, slang or informal expressions for a bad situation that causes trouble for a person and seems impossible to get out of.

An example:
A guy lost a smartphone with a ton of personal information on it, in a public place. The smartphone had his logins, passwords, credit card info, personal porn and selfies. It is unlikely that he will get it back.

> That poor guy is ______
>   (or)
>   That situation is like _____

I am looking for idioms to describe the situation when someone is in deep trouble and unable to fix it.

Comment: This is too broad.  There are dozens of possibilities.

Comment: Disaster has to be the condition followed by any of a 1000 curses.  Unless you live in France, digital files are forever.

Comment: Maybe "Catch-22," "Double bind," "Between a rock and a hard place" (or, more archaically, "Between Scylla and Charybdis")

Comment: "To be in a mess", "To be screwed" or "when you find yourself in deep shit, there's nothing to chirp about".

Comment: @Chenmunka What exactly is too broad for you? Possibilities? Which possibilities? Someone is in a bad situation and unable to fix it. The example was given in the question. Isn't it clear enough?

Comment: @SAH these phrases are not suited to the situation I described.

Comment: I refer to phrases that are possibilities as answers to your question.  Without even trying I can think of 20 or so idioms that are in frequent, widespread use.  Many readers will do the same. This fits the close reason "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One that I use is "up a creek without a paddle". It implies being at the mercy of whatever the creek may bring to you, whether it be the shore, rapids, or being dumped out of the boat entirely.

Comment: An off-color variant is "up shit creek" or even "up shit creek without a paddle"

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.  @Silenus

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - The question has been edited and now I would like to suggest **"in a stew"**.

- The poor guy is [**in a stew.**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-a-stew)

> If someone is in a stew, that ​person is in a ​difficult ​situation that ​causes them to ​feel ​worried or ​upset. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-a-stew)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that fellow is in a pickle.